# Is all information of history transactions(of other users also) maintained by every user/Customer of Bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain

I am trying to learn the blockchain technology and implement it in our existing product ecosystem. Bitcoin is the best example of blockchain technology.
I have read multiple articles on the internet and found that blockchain is a distributed ledger and every participant in it will maintain a copy of the ledger.

There are around millions of people holding bitcoins.
So all these customers maintain copy of ledger at their end ?
And when we make a new bitcoin transaction we need every other customer's consensus to make transaction successful ?

Or is it that there are a set of bitcoin minors who act on behalf of these customer's and maintain these ledger at their end ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. You should try to ask on https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

A Blockchain is a network where everyone is at the same level, i.e. there isn't a centralized authority that holds the system. So, everyone stores all the information.

> And when we make a new bitcoin transaction we need every other
>   customer's consensus to make transaction successful ? Or is it that there are a set of bitcoin minors who act on behalf of these customer's and maintain these ledger at their end ?

The consensus is reached among all the participants of the Blockchain. In the case of Bitcoin, the mechanism used for it is the Proof of Work (PoW).

- When a node of Bitcoin gets a new transaction, it verifies the transaction. If all is ok, the node broadcast the transaction to the rest of the nodes of Bitcoin. Every node, when it receives a new transaction, validates it.
- The nodes of Bitcoin are miners. They are trying to generate a block. That block will store many transactions. When a node generates a block, the block is broadcast to the rest of the Bitcoin nodes.
- When a node receives a new block, it verifies the block, i.e, verifies that all the transactions are valid and the block is correct. If so, the node adds the new block to its blockchain.
- All the nodes store the same Blockchain. Also, all the nodes verify all the transactions and all blocks.

Comment: I understand how it works. Most of the customers of the bitcoin buy bitcoins using some exchanges like Zebpay and all. They actually dont have capability to mine the bitcoins. So is it that the bitcoin exchange do the actual mining and maintain the whole ledger information at their end ?

Comment: No, there are a lot of people mining. However, it's very difficult to mine a Block with your PC so, people join to pools. People share their computing capacity to mine Blocks. Also, nowadays there is hardware designed for mining.